# Why ajax of Rails Application not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1.This code of `welcome/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag('search', method:"get",remote:true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<div id="results">
    <%= render 'searchresults' %>
</div>
```

2.This code of `_searchresults.html.erb`:

```
<table  class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr> 
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.description %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

3. This code of `WelcomeController`:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    return @articles
  end
  def search
    @query = params[:q]
    @articles = Article.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{@query}%")
    respond_to do |format|      
        format.html { redirect_to @articles }       
        format.js      
    end
  end
end
```

4. Add routes:

> ```
> root 'welcome#index'
>  get 'welcome/search'
> ```

5. code of search.js.erb:

   $('#results').html("<%= render 'searchresults' %>")

Result 
[image]
Why ajax of Rails Application not working?
Thanks all.
I using rails 5.2, ruby 2.5.

Comment: Please include your error stack from your console.

Comment: @jvilian: it only occur error when i view debug. it not got to error page.

Comment: Your console *must* show an error. You won't see it on the page because you're using JS.

Comment: @DT Kindly post you error which you showing at rails server.(error stack).

Comment: i'm sorry, i had edit question, first error, i had fix.

Comment: @DT Probably its error in `search.js.erb` check some fixes in below answer,and let me know for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="results">    
  <%= render 'searchresults', articles: @articles %>
</div>
```

It's always a good practice to pass local variable   in partial-

```
$('#results').html("<%= j render 'welcome/searchresults', articles: @articles%>");
```

In `_searchresults.html.erb`

```
<table  class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr> 
  <% articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.description %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```